# Testing custom devise session controller using RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I'm using a custom Devise SessionsController:

```
#custom_sessions_controller.rb
class CustomSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
end
```

In my routes.rb devise is set up like this:

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :custom_users, { 
    :singular => 'custom_user',
    :class_name => 'CustomUser', 
    :path => "/", 
    :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout' },
    :controllers => { :sessions => "custom_sessions" } 
}
```

I would like to write a simple rspec test:

```
#custom_sessions_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
describe CustomSessionsController, :type => :controller do

  describe "login" do
    before do
      setup_controller_for_warden
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:custom_user]
      @my_user = FactoryGirl.create(:custom_user) # creates user with valid credentials
    end

    it "should succeed with valid credentials" do
      sign_in @my_user
      curr_user = assigns(:current_custom_user)

      expect(curr_user).to eq(@my_user)
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

In my `rails_helper.rb` the following lines are present:

```
require 'devise'
...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers , :type => :controller
  ...
```

The problem is that `curr_user` in the test is alway `nil`. What am I doing wrong? Or how to test a custom devise session controller? Or how to log in in - other - tests using a custom devise session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using

```
@controller.current_custom_user
```

instead of

```
assigns(:current_custom_user)
```

seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

instead of:

> describe CustomSessionsController, :type => :controller do

try:

> RSpec.describe CustomSessionsController, :type => :controller do

Hope it works!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't solve my issue.

Comment: There is none request in a action in your spec. Take a look at: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/controller-specs to see how it properly works.